# Jpackage 'missing .jpackage.xml file in app-image dir' on jdk19

Tags: macos, jpackage, java-19

I have a script which builds my Java application using `jpackage` for macOS.

First, it generates the app, then it packages it to a DMG file. This used to work with Java 18, but now with the new Java 19 it fails with `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: Missing .jpackage.xml file in app-image dir (/my-project/target/artifact-image)`.
The script is basically like the following:

```
${java.home}/bin/jpackage --type app-image --input ${copied-none-modular-dependencies} \
  --resource-dir ${project.build.directory}/package --module-path ${copied-modular-dependencies} \
  --add-modules ${app.additional.modules} --module ${app.main.module}/${app.main.class} \
  --dest ${artifact.image.path} --name "My awesome app" --app-version ${project.version} --verbose \
  --mac-package-name "My awesome app" --mac-package-identifier com.example.awesome.app
${java.home}/bin/jpackage --type dmg --app-image ${artifact.image.path} \
  --resource-dir ${project.build.directory}/package --dest ${artifact.output.path} \
  --name "My awesome app" --app-version ${project.version} --verbose
```

Is this `.jpackage.xml` file something new? How should it be generated? I cannot find it in the directory indicated by the error...

Comment: Seems to originate from here: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk19/pull/9 if my reading is correct, the first command should generate the `.jpacakge.xml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out! My actual problem was not, that the file was not present. I've simply looked at the wrong place. The file was present under `/my-project/target/artifact-image/My awesome app.app/Contents/app/.jpackage.xml`.

The root problem was, that the `--app-image` parameter now should reference the `My awesome app.app` directory directly and no more (as in Java 18) its parent (in my case `/my-project/target/artifact-image`).